# "Null value error" in firestore simulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to reproduce an example from the official Firestore [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions?authuser=0#data_validation). Everything you need to know is on the screenshot. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: where is this simulator? is it the same as the emulator?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that there's no actual document at `/cities/moscow`

Comment: What does this answer mean and how do you know there is no document there?

Comment: @Jay, I know there's no document there because I didn't create one. As soon as I add document with the name "moscow" to the "cities" collection the error disappears. Instead I get a message either saying read allowed or not. It's just a confusing and not very descriptive error. Thanks you for the answer!

Comment: Ah. I see. While there may no document at that location, the bigger picture for the rules issue was that the fields trying to read are not present in any of the locations. I think my answer identifies the issue and provides a solution as well. If it helped, please accept it so it can help others!

Answer (score 6):

A bit more explanation would have made manidos's answer a good one.

It seems like `resources` should be used only for rules involving data that have been already written; e.g. `delete`, `read`, `update`, etc.

If you want to set rules on data that "will be" written, use `getAfter`.

Comment: If you're writing you can access the data you're going to write via `request.resource`

Answer (score 6):

The issue is - as manidos - pointed out that the document /cities/moscow doesn't exist and hence the document is not accessible. However, a cleaner way to specify your rule is:

```
allow read: if (resource == null) || (resource.data.visibility == 'public')
```

It allows an application to query data that doesn't exist without blowing up with a security exception.

Answer (score 3):

The key is to reading through the comments.

> Many apps store access control information as fields on documents in
>   the database. Cloud Firestore Security Rules can dynamically allow or
>   deny access based on document data:

and then

> // Allow the user to read data if the document has the 'visibility' field set to 'public'

If you look at the example data provided in the guide

```
let citiesRef = db.collection("cities")
citiesRef.document("SF").setData([
    "name": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "country": "USA",
    "capital": false,
    "population": 860000,
    "regions": ["west_coast", "norcal"]
])
```

There is no 'visibility' field, however there is a name, state country field etc.

If you want to work with that data set, add a 'visibility' field to each city and set it's value to 'public'

```
 citiesRef.document("SF").setData([
        "name": "San Francisco",
        "visibility": "public"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still learning but the issue with

allow read: if **(resource == null)** || (resource.data.visibility == 'public')

is when you use such a rule for /cities/**{doc}**.  From what i can see resource == null whenever you search for documents without an exact document ID; the above rule would show everything, private and public, for /cities/{doc} because resource always == null.

From what i've been able to piece together one must make use of the get(...) statement to directly access a document's data whenever within a match that can return 1 or more documents, so

**get(/database/...).data.visibility == 'public'**